# Instantiating class with interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, class, interface, instantiation, parameterized-constructor

Hi this might be trivial but I am trying to understand the class instantiation using interface. So below is my code:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    string GetMemberDisplayName();
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly Manager _manager;

    public Repository() {}

    public Repository(string connectionName)
    {
        _manager = new Manager(connectionName);
    }

    public string GetMemberDisplayName(string ID)
    {
        return "FooFoo";
    }
}
```

Now in another class that uses the repository class functionality has instantiated it as follows:

```
public class LogServiceHelper
{
    readonly IRepository _alrAttendance;
    readonly IRepository _alrUsers;

    public LogServiceHelper()
    {
        _alrAttendance = new Repository("value1");
        _alrUsers = new Repository("value2");
    }

    public string GetMemberName(string empId)
    {
        return _alrUsers.GetMemberDisplayName(empId);
    }
}
```

My question is if this is correct way to instantiate a class with parameterized constructor. And if yes, then second question is why do we need interface in this case. We could directly instantiate the class without creating the interface?

Comment: The interfaces are there so that you don't have `new` up concrete instances and can inject them instead. Right now your constructor is not parameterized.

Comment: This is of course fine but not the best practice. You should look at DI principle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how to invoke a parameterized constructor, but no, that's not what you should be doing.

As you have it, `LogServiceHelper` has a hard dependency on the `Repository` class, and so you are right, the interfaces don't buy you anything. However, if they were *injected*:

```
public LogServiceHelper(IRepository attendanceRepo, IRepository userRepo)
{
    _alrAttendance = attendanceRepo;
    _alrUsers = userRepo;
}
```

You suddenly gain the benefits of abstraction. Notably that a unit test could pass in fake repositories, and that you can switch to another implementation of `IRepository` without changing `LogServiceHelper`.

The next question is then "Who creates the `Repository` concrete class?". For that, I refer you to the variety of DI/IoC containers out there, such as Autofac, Unity, and NInject.

Answer (score 0):

> We could directly instantiate the class without creating the
>   interface?

This is indeed true and it might work without any problem. But then we are coming to the crucial questions:

- *Is my code testable, how would I test this piece of code?*
- *Could I easily change the behavior without changing LogServiceHelper*

If you don't rely on the abstraction, the answer to the above questions is unfortunately, **no**. Luckily there is something called SOLID and the D stands for [Dependency Injection Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

```
public LogServiceHelper(IRepository alrAttendance, IRepository alrUsers)
{
    _alrAttendance = alrAttendance;
    _alrUsers = alrUsers;
}
```

So, with this simple change, you made decoupling of the moduls and all of a sudden you are relying on the abstraction which gains a lot of benefits to design.